Adding multiple .STL or .OBJ file render into single canvas
The goal is to render multiple files into single canvas. I tried and  it worked but there is some issues like fading colors, long gap between the models.
here is my code block . I tried using threejs, I tried to load it multiple times with multiple files but the goal is all model ( multiple files) should be in same canvas and response like single model.
my code block
here is what I got
and my goal is like this

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].
